# Does this noun phrase denote the result of the verb?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, ellipsis, direct-objects

> “I think I’ll be a clown when I get grown,” said Dill.
>   Jem and
>   I stopped in our tracks.
>   ‘Yes sir, a clown,” he said. “There
>   ain’t one thing in this world I can do about folks except laugh, so
>   I’m gonna join the circus and laugh **my head off**.”
>  (Harper
>   Lee, To Kill A Mockingbird)

Is ‘my head off’ the result of the action of ‘laugh’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Laugh my head off](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/laugh#laugh_1__38) is an idiom, and it means "to laugh very loudly and for a long time."

Answer (score 0):

As Kiamaluno points out, "Laugh <one's> head off" is an idiom.  It can be grammatically parsed as follows:

> I'm gonna… laugh my head off.
>   [I am going to]… laugh [so hard that] my head [falls] off [of my body].

"my head" is the direct object of the verb "laugh".  "off" is a preposition, which describes where "my head" goes.